# Only adding Keys and Value to an Arrays when the If-condition is fulfilled

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

So I'm currently working on a PHP project. Now I'm trying to build an Array I want to output later on. The Array should only be filled with Value when the if-condition is true.

I cant seem to find any working code or any help. I don't really know what to try next.

```
$maxTestDuration = 20;

$startTime = strtotime("now");
$endTime = strtotime("+1 hour");
$testDuration = $endTime - $startTime;

$currentTest = "Test1";
$test2 = "test2";
$test3 = "test3";
$test4 = "test4";

$testDuration2 = "300";
$testDuration3 = "10";
$testDuration4 = "5420";


if ($testDuration > $maxTestDuration)
    {
        $overTimeTests =
        [
        $currentTest => $testDuration,
        "test2" =>  "300",
        "test3" => "2000",
        "test4" => "5420",
        ];
    }

foreach ($overTimeTests as $testName => $testDuration)
{
    $testText = $testName.": ".$testDuration." seconds\n";
    echo $testText;
}
```

The Result should be an Output of just the three tests that run under 20 seconds. Instead, it shows all four tests. I also tried changing `$endTime` so that test1 would be faster than 20 seconds but then I get errors, that the array is empty.

Comment: When do you set `$overTimeTests`?  As you only set it if the condition is met, then you also need to set it somewhere else as well for when the condition isn't met.

Comment: _“The Result should be an Output of just the three tests that run under 20 seconds.”_ - and where and how exactly did you try and check for this? The place where you _output_ this data, is inside the foreach loop - so any such check would need to happen in there.

Comment: I only set the Array in the if because, if the tests runs faster than 20 seconds I want to ignore it

Comment: 1) `$overTimeTests` only exists if your if condition is filled, you need to put it outside so your foreach won't give you error. 2) Right now you only do ONE test (`if ($testDuration > $maxTestDuration)`), what about other test ? Please edit your question with desired output it's not very clear